# How do I set margin and padding on a FontImage?

Tags: codenameone

I am using createFixed, passing in 0 as the padding:

```
 FontImage fontImage = FontImage.createFixed(RAFont.RA_CYCLE, RAFont.rpgAwesomeFont, RAFont.COLOR_RED, getSizeIconSmall(), getSizeIconSmall(), 0);
```

But the component inspector shows the padding is 18, apparently inherited from Label.

I don't see any way at all to set margin.  There is also no setUUID method to do it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FontImage` is an image which isn't a `Component` so it has no margin or padding. The component inspector shows you the padding/margin of the label you set it to. You can see the UIID of that component within the inspector and also change the UIID within that tool to `Container` which always has 0 margin/padding.

Comment: Thanks!  I see now that when I add an image to a container, it creates a Label using that image and then actually adds that.  So the solution is to just create the Label myself using the image (new Label(fontImage);) and then I can adjust the Label as needed before adding it to the container.